# Java JDBC Index out of range

Tags: java

I have below code to insert data into database, I tried searching similar questions above but it didn't help me to solve the problem, so please allow me to ask new question and help me. Thanks

```
public void insertUser(String image, String fullname, boolean gender, String email, String address, int status, String mobile) throws SQLException {
        String query = "INSERT INTO db_ite1.user VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try {
            conn = new DBContext().getConnection();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setInt(1, getNewId());
            ps.setString(2, image);
            ps.setString(3, fullname);
            ps.setBoolean(4, gender);
            ps.setString(5, email);
            ps.setString(6, address);
            ps.setInt(7, status);
            ps.setString(8, mobile);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            closeConnection(conn, ps, rs);
        }
    }
```

because in my database it is not set to auto-increment ID, so I have to write a function to get new ID

```
public int getNewId() throws SQLException {
        String query = "select max(user.id) from db_ite1.user";
        try {
            conn = new DBContext().getConnection();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                return (rs.getInt(1) + 1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I checked and it error in getNewID() function, if I use `ps.setInt(1, 13);` it works, but if I use `ps.setInt(1, getNewID());` there is an error with it

```
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

Comment: Why are you _not_ taking advantage of your databases's ability to generate an auto increment primary key value?  It is pretty non typical to be managing the ID yourself from Java, as you are trying to do above.

Comment: Where are conn, ps and rs declared?

Comment: `getNewId()` won't work properly if one is trying to update the data and other one is trying to retrieve data at a same time. If it's primary key your insert will fail. Better to use database's auto increment column.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen yes, this is homework of my friend, he design bad database, so I can use AI for database. Thanks for your comment

Comment: BTW: You should use `try-with-resources` not closing th connection by your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
// you have set ps for the `insert`
ps.setInt(1, getNewId());
// now within `getNewId` `ps` is now being set to the `select`
```

Either make `ps` local variables or do the `getNewId` before creating the `insert` `ps`

Answer (score -2):

I used this and it worked, I solved the problem

```
int id = dao.getNewId();
dao.insertUser(id, "test", "test", true, "test", "test", 0, "test");
```

```
public void insertUser(int id, String image, String fullname, boolean gender, String email, String address, int status, String mobile) throws SQLException {
        String query = "INSERT INTO db_ite1.user VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try {
            conn = new DBContext().getConnection();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.setString(2, image);
            ps.setString(3, fullname);
            ps.setBoolean(4, gender);
            ps.setString(5, email);
            ps.setString(6, address);
            ps.setInt(7, status);
            ps.setString(8, mobile);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            closeConnection(conn, ps, rs);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You did, but why, please explain.

Comment: i don't know why, but if i passed the ID variable from outside instead of using ```ps.setInt(1, getNewId());``` it worked

Comment: see my answer for the reason